# How to I print vocab words that appear over a certain number of times

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using scipy and numpy, here is the code I am using:

```
for tag, count in zip(vocab, dist):
    print count, tag
```

How do I print only the tags that occur over 100 times?

Comment: Why you are using zip then? You first need to create a dictionary with tag and count.

Comment: Thank you Sijan. I figured it out. I am using CountVectorizer and I needed to use min_df